# Google App Engine passing template variables into view with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, google-app-engine, templates

My `main.py` has the following variables:

```
'booking_times':
 {
   'Today': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00'],
   'Tue': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00'],
   'Wed': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00']
 }
```

In my view I would like to display them in table:

```
-----------------------
Today  | Tue   | Wed   | // line 1
9:00   | 9:00  | 9:00  | // line 2
12:00  | 12:00 | 12:00 |
```

I have 2 questions:

(1) As an example, how would I loop through for line 2 which are each a `<td>` html tag?

(2) My line 1 is as follows, but it  outputs as `Tue  | Today  | Wed` instead of `Today  | Tue   | Wed   |`:

```
{% for day in booking_times %}
<td>{{day}}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python, here is one thing you could try. Note that this starts with a slightly different setup of your `booking_times` variable, but hopefully the concept makes sense. The general idea is that we first create a sort order that we will use to sort our values. We then use `zip` to create a new list-of-lists, which will begin with the days and then follow with the hours in each subsequent list.

```py
booking_times = {
   'Today': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00'],
   'Tue': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00'],
   'Wed': ['9:00', '12:00', '14:00', '15:00', '19:00', '20:00']
 }

# Create a new booking_times variable that is a list-of-list,
# leading with the 'days' and followed by one list for each time
sorted_keys = ['Today', 'Tue', 'Wed']
booking_times = [sorted_keys] + zip(*(booking_times[s] for s in sorted_keys))
```

Here is what `booking_times` looks like at this point in time when iterated over with a simple `for row in booking_times: print row`:

```
['Today', 'Tue', 'Wed']
('9:00', '9:00', '9:00')
('12:00', '12:00', '12:00')
('14:00', '14:00', '14:00')
('15:00', '15:00', '15:00')
('19:00', '19:00', '19:00')
('20:00', '20:00', '20:00')
```

You can then pass that value into your template and iterate over it in essentially the same way you are above:

```html
{% for day in booking_times %}
   <tr>
   {% for item in day %}
       <td>{{ item }}</td> 
   {% endfor %}
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I can't test the templating right now, but this outputs the following when modified to work with simple print statements:

```
Today   Tue Wed
9:00    9:00    9:00
12:00   12:00   12:00
14:00   14:00   14:00
15:00   15:00   15:00
19:00   19:00   19:00
20:00   20:00   20:00
```

This may deviating a bit far from your current setup, so happy to adjust if necessary.

Comment: This works perfectly :) could you just fix `{% endfor % }` to `{% endfor %}` as this was showing the template syntax error. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Sayanee Ha, I actually made an almost-identical syntax error on a previous question of yours (which you corrected). We make a good team! Good luck with everything :)

Comment: Thanks a huge tonne @RocketDonkey :) I didn't realised you were helping me again!

Comment: @Sayanee No problem at all :)